# Getting Feed Format not supported when trying to access OData webservice

Tags: odata

After configuring Dot net Odata webservice, when I am trying to execute it, it is giving "Feed Format not Supported"

```
http://localhost:8091/odata.svc//Pages(ItemId=1212306,PublicationId=232)
```

However when trying this `http://localhost:8091/odata.svc/Publications` it is giving proper result.

Please suggest!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you get this message in all browsers?

If it's just IE, you may just need to change the settings here:

[image]

This was first explained in Nuno's article on setting up the oData Web Service [here](http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/deployer-and-odata-4.aspx).